# I can't start vim in conemu

Tags: vim, conemu

I'm trying to start vim in conemu.

If I add to the tasks just

```
vim.exe
```

It starts vim, but it is in black and white, and it is super super unbelievably slow.

I've tried most of the commands but the tool seems just impossible to use.

Any help for a configuration???

vim is in

```
d:\sbin\vim\vim90\vim.exe
```

Comment: LOL what. Sorry, I'm using windows... I'm trying to use vim in conemu.

Comment: Maybe try a different terminal app.